# Spring cannot find xml file

Tags: java, spring, maven, javabeans

Spring not able located the xml config file. spring.xml file is located in the java folder
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In maven the non-java classpath resources like xml should be placed in `src\main\resources`.

From the screenshot I can see that you don't have `resources` folder in `src\main`. Create a folder named `resources` in `src\main` and move the `spring.xml` into it and try.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the xml file in IDEA, and click the copy path selection, the u can choose the right path in your java file